# Which of the following layouts is better in terms of design and usability (Online date renting site)?

Tags: website-design

This is proposal number one:

[image]

This is proposal number two:

[image]

Which one is better in term of design, usability, accessibility, and visual appeal?

Comment: Would I have to create two signups to do both?

Comment: This only got so many views because it's about a site for renting a date!!!

Comment: You need to spell check option 1. Occasional has two C's.

Comment: I'm guessing the concept of "date renting" (at least branded with that term) is highly specific to a certain culture?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At #1, it's obvious to a moron in a hurry how the site works. I might think "neat idea", and immediately realize that I'm going to rent more than be rented. Overcoming the sadness of this realization, I know where to click.

#2 follows the  (generally good) philosophy to start with *benefits* instead of *technology*. It's wrong in this case because it is **exactly the same promise gazillions of other social sites make** - so you ar losing your unique proposition. If you throw in "and lose weight", you have the perfect Web 2.0 snake oil.

To make matters worse, there's NO way I can see where I could find out how you want to keep that promise. At that point, I want to neither sign up nor login. Asking me to do that before telling me what for is a certain way to *not* get my email address.

---

On the design: #1 is very clear and up-front. The "cute girl with a flower" conveys all the hapyp romantic ideas you'd associate with a date, avoiding / countering the naughty / seedy aspects one could see in "rent a date". Excellent!

Compared to that, #2 loses. Big time. Why would I want to rent a mouse? Is that a walking billboard? At best, I'd think of teenage furries.

(Maybe that image conveys a different meaning in your culture, but that's what I see. Side note: 'chen' is not my last name).

---

Regarding usability: Don't split the signup into rentee and renter. I'd still like to entertain the idea that someone might want to rent me some day. Generally, new users might expect to act as both at that point. one signup form destroys the neat symmetry of that page, but a single, centered signup button should do (maybe acting as "link" between rentee and renter).

Answer (score 4):

In first there’s a clear understanding of what to do and (if you’ll write good text) why is it all about. Second one is just design, not a site that may work.

I just think that registration should be enabled by default, not login — new users will go in faster, returning users will not see that screen at all because of stored session.

Answer (score 4):

I can't understand anything of the second design. Just by looking at it I can't see what I can click to start using this service.

The only suggestion I have to improve the first design would perhaps be that there would be only one set of Sign up and login. When you sign up you choose whether to rent or to be rented.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely the first one! - the second says nothing about the service (which is still not clear for me)

Rather requiring users to register, first let them try the service, and register later! Try it now button - and if they like the UI and the idea they will definitely sign up

Answer (score 2):

You misspelled p-r-o-s-t-i-t-u-t-i-o-n.

Answer (score 1):

I like the first one as well....it simply makes more sense to me and comes across as more put together than #2...it seems to be more of an attempt to be creative but is not really delivering....